# Update JSSOR Idle time dynamically

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am using JSSOR Slider [JSSOR Link](http://www.jssor.com/) as my image slider. I added an option to change the slide idle duration. ***My issue is that when I set the $Idle property it does not change the idle duration.***

```
jssor_slider1.$Idle=2000;
```

Is there a way to change the slide Idle without completely destroying and rebuilding the slider?

Answer (score 0):

The $Idle option is not available to change dynamically.

But you can set idle for each slide individually. And you can change it dynamically.

```
<div u="slides" ...>
    <div data-idle="2000"></div>
    ...
</div>
```